# R: Create a linear mixed-effect model loop that removes one fixed independent variable, then adds it back in and removes another

Tags: r, regression, mixed-models

I'm looking for a way to create a linear mixed-effect model loop that removes one fixed effect independent variable, runs the model, adds it back in, and removes another fixed independent variable from the model.

For example:

`library(lme4)`

`L1 <- lmer(cyl ~ disp + hp + mpg (carb|gear), mtcars)`

How can I create a loop of this model so that each new regression loop iteration removes a single fixed effect independent variable, adds it back in on the next iteration, and removes a different fixed independent variable?

Doing this would produce these models:

Original full model: `lmer(cyl ~ disp + mpg +  (carb|gear), mtcars)`

Partial model with mpg removed: `lmer(cyl ~ disp + hp + (carb|gear), mtcars)`

Partial model with mpg re-added and disp removed: `lmer(cyl ~ hp + mpg  (carb|gear), mtcars)`

Partial model with disp re-added and hp removed:  `lmer(cyl ~ disp + mpg  (carb|gear), mtcars)`

I am also curious how I can add each model to a list after each loop iteration.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map` over the fixed variables constructing the formula, `fo`, using `reformulate` and run `lmer`.  This will produce a named list of `"lmerMod"` objects, one for each component of `fixed` such that that model omits that component.  The full model will have an empty name.

```
library(lme4)

fixed <- c("", "disp", "hp", "mpg")

f <- function(v, data) {
  fo <- reformulate(c(setdiff(fixed, v), "(carb | gear)"), "cyl")
  cat("Running", format(fo), "\n")
  lmer(fo, data = data)
}
out <- Map(f, fixed, MoreArgs = list(data = mtcars))
## Running cyl ~ disp + hp + mpg + (carb | gear) 
## boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
## Running cyl ~ hp + mpg + (carb | gear) 
## Running cyl ~ disp + mpg + (carb | gear) 
## boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
## Running cyl ~ disp + hp + (carb | gear)
```

### drop1

Also, lme4 has a `"merMod"` method for `drop1` which will use `extractAIC` to calculate the AIC value for each single term deletion.

```
fm <- lmer(cyl ~ disp + hp + mpg + (carb | gear), data = mtcars)
## boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular

drop1(fm)
## boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
## Single term deletions
##
## Model:
## cyl ~ disp + hp + mpg + (carb | gear)
##        npar    AIC
## <none>      79.239
## disp      1 86.511
## hp        1 81.417
## mpg       1 78.901
```

This is similar to the following which shows the degrees of freedom and AIC for each single term deletion.

```
sapply(out, extractAIC)
##                  disp       hp      mpg
## [1,]  8.00000  7.00000  7.00000  7.00000
## [2,] 79.23877 86.51109 81.41726 78.90149
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Added information on `drop1` .

Comment: Thanks for the added information! Would it be possible to apply your first function to a list of sample datasets with the exact same variables? For example: If the original "mtcars" data has 32 rows and I created x new datasets from the original dataset all with varying amounts of rows, then I added all of these datasets to a list, how could I run this dataset list through your function?

Comment: I would be using the following to create the list of datasets:                                                           
```output<- list()
iterations <- 5
for(i in 1:iterations){
  output[[i]] <- mtcars <- mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars), size = 15, replace = FALSE), ]

}```

Comment: Have modified `f` to also accept the data set.  Using that `f` we can run this: `L <- list(mtcars32 = mtcars, mtcars16 = mtcars[1:16,]); out <- Map(function(data) Map(f, fixed, MoreArgs = list(data = data)), L)`

Comment: Masterful, thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: I posted another question that uses your code and was curious if you could help me solve it. Thanks in advance!  [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71081973/r-getting-mean-square-error-from-each-linear-mixed-effect-model-in-a-list-and-s)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `MuMIn` package for model averaging. You normally start by running the full model, and the `dredge` function can be used to iteratively run models with all combinations of predictors. You can specify effects that you want to keep consistent e.g. your (carb|gear) random effect. The outputs can give you a table of results for each model.

Comment: Thanks! I will be sure to check this out.